# Trouble in assigning value to array inside an object drived from a class

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

In my angular project, I have made a class:

```
    export class Test {
      mcq: { question: string, options:string[]}[] = [];
    } //blueprint of an object having a question and an array of strings
```

In other component where this class is imported I want to drive an object from class test, which I have done this way:

```
let exampleTest = new Test();
exampleTest.mcq = [{ question: 'any question?', options[0]: 'a', options[1]: 'b', options[2]: 'c', options[3]: 'd'}]
```

the `options[0]` part in `exampleTest.mcq` is giving error.

Its been one hour I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I have also tried `exampleTest.mcq.options[0] = 'a';` still not working.

Comment: That's not how you create an array in an object, you'll have to do something like: `{ question: 'any question?', options: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] }`

Comment: How can be someone so stupid :p. Thank you :) @JeffMercado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way you're building the `options` array inside your `exampleTest.mcq` object. The current approach you are using looks like this:

```
{ options[0]: 'a', options[1]: 'b', options[2]: 'c' }
```

which is incorrect syntax for constructing an array in an object. What you really want is

```
{ options: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }
```

The line of code above will attach an array of strings to the key `options`, which seems to be what you're looking for.

In short, use the following code for building `exampleTest.mcq`:

```
let exampleTest = new Test();
exampleTest.mcq = [{ question: 'any question?', options: ['a', 'b', 'c'] }];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you create an array in an object, you'll have to do something like: `{ question: 'any question?', options: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ] }` – Curtsy: @Jeff Mercado

Comment: Looks like you got an answer as I was writing mine! This is the correct way to do it.